# finding do_action function

Tags: wordpress

I've got this.

```
do_action( 'bp_before_directory_groups_list' );
```

and I cant find the corresponding add action to trace the function that is called. Anyone know what im doing wrong?

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there isn't one, as it may be just there so as to enable other plugins to hook into it But to check, run this code after loading all the plugins, like in a theme file:

```
print_r($wp_filter['bp_before_directory_groups_list']);
```

$wp_filter is a global variable that stores all the action hooks and filters added by plugins.

Comment: Then there's no function hooked to that action.